# VS2012 project containg Fakes assembly definition rebuilds always

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-fakes

Originally we found this problem in complex solution, but now I can reproduce it on dummy project too.

If I create project in VS2012 premium (update 4) and add Fakes assembly for one of the references, it seems that project will always rebuild regardless of anything being changed. I.e. I build the project then clicking the build button again will result in rebuilding the project.

Turning on diagnostic build info, it seems that root cause of the problem is that tool compiling the .fakes file is touching the .Fakes.dll file, hence VS thinks that something has changed:

```
1>Using "Touch" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Touch" (TaskId:11)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      Files=
1>          D:\work\Ch24_2014_PreEC\UnitTestProject1\FakesAssemblies\mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll
1>          D:\work\Ch24_2014_PreEC\UnitTestProject1\FakesAssemblies\System.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll
1>          D:\work\Ch24_2014_PreEC\UnitTestProject1\FakesAssemblies\mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.fakesconfig
1>          D:\work\Ch24_2014_PreEC\UnitTestProject1\FakesAssemblies\System.4.0.0.0.Fakes.fakesconfig (TaskId:11)
1>  Touching "D:\work\Ch24_2014_PreEC\UnitTestProject1\FakesAssemblies\mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll". (TaskId:11)
1>  Touching "D:\work\Ch24_2014_PreEC\UnitTestProject1\FakesAssemblies\System.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll". (TaskId:11)
1>  Touching "D:\work\Ch24_2014_PreEC\UnitTestProject1\FakesAssemblies\mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.fakesconfig". (TaskId:11)
1>  Touching "D:\work\Ch24_2014_PreEC\UnitTestProject1\FakesAssemblies\System.4.0.0.0.Fakes.fakesconfig". (TaskId:11)
1>Done executing task "Touch". (TaskId:11)

[...]

1>Input file "D:\work\Ch24_2014_PreEC\UnitTestProject1\FakesAssemblies\System.4.0.0.0.Fakes.dll" is newer than output file "obj\Debug\UnitTestProject1.pdb".
```

Please advise on what am I doing wrong and how to get around this, so that the project would not rebuild redundantly all the time.

Thanks in advance

**Edited**

For clarification, here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create C# project of your choice (I've tried unit test and console app)
2. Add a Fakes Assembly on one of referenced assemblies (I used System in the example above)
3. Build the project
4. Build it again (not rebuild)

*Note that you don't have to add a single line of code to the solution.*

Comment: Could you post the smallest project that replicates the problem? It'll be easier for people to help you if they have something to fiddle with.

Comment: Am I mistaken or is this not the standard functionality when pressing build?

Comment: Cannot reproduce - I've created empty project, added fakes assemblies for System, then hit Build, and in 1 minute, hit Build again - files were not updated in my Bin and Obj folders (is this what happens with you?).

Comment: If you have a project that reproduces it, I suggest 1) confirming the bug still exists in VS2013 2) posting it as a bug on connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @antiduh : the smallest project is the one described

Comment: @QBM5 : no, that would be the "Rebuild" button

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin : which VS are you using?

Comment: @hege - There's not a drop of code provided anywhere in your question. No project --> people can't help you.

Comment: @MobyDisk : unfortunately the original solution is bound to VS2012 but I will do the VS2013 test tomorrow, out of curiousity :)

Comment: @hege, it's VS 2012 Premium, update 4, just like yours.

Comment: @hege I reproduced the exact issue on 2012 update 4: every time the test project got rebuilt without being changed. Then I started Process Monitor to see what's happening, I built the project and nothing suspicious in the list of events for my fakes DLL. `MSBuild`, `csc` and `devenv` each have opened the file for reading and then closed it (several times of course). And then the weirdest thing happened: It is not being rebuilt anymore. Somehow observing the criminals made them stop the crime! Did we get some quantum mechanics situation here where the observer influences the system?

Comment: Just tested in VS2013u3RC and it doesn't rebuild there after initial build. In VS2012u4 it does. Seems like a bug that was fixed in 2013.

Comment: Comparing the two `.targets` files, there are too many differences to quickly pinpoint the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit registry settings of visual studio. Set `"U2DCheckVerbosity"=dword:00000001` at `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\General]`

Then you will see in output, why visual studio thinks, full rebuild is neccessary.
Original info is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2014/08/04/how-to-investigate-rebuilding-in-visual-studio-when-nothing-has-changed.aspx).

[UPDATE]

Things changed slightly for vs2017, instructions are [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/161997/full-build-every-time-with-155.html)

> To manually update the "fast up-to-date check" registry setting in VS 2017, do the following:
>
> - Close VS 2017 and wait 20-30 seconds for it to release its private registy hive.
> - Run regedit.exe
> - Select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE File --> Load Hive...
> - Go to folder %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
> - Select the 15.0_* folder that does not end with Exp
> - Select the privateregistry.bin file in that folder.
>     For example, C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_4eff8961\privateregistry.bin
> - For Load Hive's Key Name just make up a name like VSTweak
>
> The hive should now appear as HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\VSTweak.
>
> - Edit (or add) the U2DCheckVerbosity dword (32-bit) value to 1 (or 0 to disable) under:
>     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\VSTweak\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_4eff8961\General
> - Select the hive root node (e.g., VSTweak)
> - File --> Unload Hive...
> - Confirm unloading the hive.
> - Start VS and build stuff.
>
> Get messages that indicate problems like: Project 'Common' is not up to date. Error (0x8000FFFF).

Comment: This will not help the OP, as your recommended registry key indicates v12, which is Visual Studio 2013.  The OP's problem is with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: No, it will help, just use 11 instead of 12 in the registry path.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the very same issue because of some references to external files: when `CopyToOutputDirectory` property was set to `Always`, a significant number of projects were rebuilt over and over again, even if no modifications to the code were made.

In VS2013 Update 2, I can't reproduce the issue by just adding a Fake Assembly, but I do can reproduce it if `CopyToOutputDirectory` for the Fake Assembly is set to either `Always` or `PreserveNewest` (i.e. *Copy if newer* in VS GUI).

In your case, I would double-check, with a text editor, if the .csproj contains any tag like this:

```
<Fakes Include="Fakes\mscorlib.fakes">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Fakes>
```

that is, `CopyToOutputDirectory` either set to `Always` or `PreserveNewest`, modifying them in

```
<Fakes Include="Fakes\mscorlib.fakes" />
```

Comment: I've read something about this issue, but AFAIK this has been fixed in either Update 3 or 4 such that the default value for Copy to Output Directory is "Do not copy", which holds true in my case too unfortunately :/

Comment: @hege In VS2013 Update 2 _Do not copy_ issue has not been fixed yet, that's why I thought my experience could have been of help to you... Did you also search for any other reference to external files in your project for which `CopyToOutputDirectory` is set to `Always` or `PreserveNewest`?

Comment: @hege Could you also double-check the last modification date of your source files? This is actually the only thing that really matters when VS has to determine whether or not to build the project again. Are you sure there isn't something wrong with your working directory? Are there other scripts running at the same time that may alter the latest modification date?

Comment: As I wrote in the original post, the problem is that for some reason the Fakes build script always touches the output file whether it's need or not, and this is why VS thinks that something has changed since the last build. I've played around yesterday with the Fakes .targets file and frankly, I don't understand why is it touching the output files - and even worse - why is it doing *after* those have been built which causes the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this same issue.  I went so far as to double-check the inputs/outputs to the BuildFakesAssemblies task in Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.targets by printing out the file and its timestamp, but couldn't see any inputs with a newer timestamp that any of the timestamps for the output files (though, I didn't check the filesize which I think is another determining factor in whether or not to execute an msbuild Target).  It is the BuildFakesAssemblies task which then touches the .fakes.dll files, which are referenced in the test project, which causes an unnecessary recompilation when nothing has actually changed.

While poking around the .targets files, I noticed that the 2013 version of the Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.targets file doesn't contain the Touch command in it.  So, I changed the .sln file which contained the test project (Format version 12 -> 13, VS 2012 -> 2013) and then retriggered my command-line build and the problem is no longer happening!  Hope this helps out the next person!